# Toggle row numbers & dotfills in table

Tags: tabularx, etoolbox

I'm trying to add automatic row numbers and dotfills to a table, with a toggle that disables them for certain rows, however it doesn't work as expected. In the MWE below, the toggle is working for row numbers, but not for the fill. How do I fix this?

In other words, **why does the toggle appear to prematurely revert to true?**

[image: example]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{etoolbox}



\AtBeginEnvironment{tabularx}{%
    \ifcscounter{c@rownumbers}{}{\newcounter{rownumbers}}%
    \setcounter{rownumbers}{0}%

    \providetoggle{showrownumber}%
    \toggletrue{showrownumber}%

    \newcommand\ifshowrownumber[1]{%
        \iftoggle{showrownumber}{#1}{}%
    }
    \newcommand\nonum{%
        \togglefalse{showrownumber}%
    }
    \newcommand\rownumberdisplay{%
        \makebox[1.5em][r]{\ifshowrownumber{%
            \stepcounter{rownumbers}\arabic{rownumbers}.%
        }}\space%
    }
    \newcommand\rowfill{%
        \ifshowrownumber{\dotfill}%
    }
    \newcommand\resetrownumber{%
        \setcounter{rownumbers}{0}%
    }
    \newcommand\rowdone{%
        \toggletrue{showrownumber}%
    }
}



\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{.9\textwidth}{r<{\rownumberdisplay} @{} X<{\rowfill} @{} r r<{\rowdone}}%
\toprule%
    \nonum & Name & A & B\\
\midrule%
    \nonum & \emph{Section} \\
    & Name & 100.0 & 3.5 \\
    \nonum & -- and Name & 10.15 & 56.8 \\
    \nonum & \emph{Section} \\
    & Name & 66.4 & 43.1 \\
    & Name & 66.4 & 43.1 \\
    & Name & 66.4 & 43.1 \\
    & Name & 66.4 & 43.1 \\
    & Name & 66.4 & 43.1 \\
    & Name & 66.4 & 43.1 \\
    & Name & 66.4 & 43.1 \\
    & Name & 66.4 & 43.1 \\
\bottomrule%
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

It is not automatic. As you manually interrupt numbering of rows, you can do the same for `\dotfill`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newcounter{rownum}
\newcommand{\getEqNo}{\refstepcounter{rownum}
                      \therownum.\,}
\newcommand\mcl[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{.9\textwidth}{>{\getEqNo}r @{} X<{\dotfill} @{} r r}
    \toprule
\mcl{}  & \mcl{Name}            & A     & B     \\
    \midrule
\mcl{}  & \mcl{\emph{Section}}  &       &       \\
        & Name                  & 100.0 &  3.5  \\
\mcl{}  & \mcl{-- and Name}     & 10.15 & 56.8  \\
\mcl{}  & \mcl{\emph{Section}}  &       &       \\
        & Name                  & 66.4  & 43.1  \\
        & Name                  & 66.4  & 43.1  \\
        & Name                  & 66.4  & 43.1  \\
        & Name                  & 66.4  & 43.1  \\
        & Name                  & 66.4  & 43.1  \\
        & Name                  & 66.4  & 43.1  \\
        & Name                  & 66.4  & 43.1  \\
        & Name                  & 66.4  & 43.1  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks pretty good, I will play around with this and report back :)

Comment: It works, but I'm not a fan of having to put `\mcl` with the names. Any idea why my toggle seems to become true prematurely?

Comment: you not have anything "dead", you only  locally changes column type. as you already do in your mwe.

Comment: Sorry, meant having to use mcl twice...

Comment: @meide, well, than you should wait on better solution. However, meantime you can use this simple and robust one. Do you have many such tables? if it is only few, is not worth to spend time for far more complex solution. But, as you wish :-)

Comment: Yes unfortunately, dozens of tables :-/ hopefully someone can explain why the toggle changes too soon.